# Google Calendar API: Insert only permission?

Tags: google-calendar-api

Is there some way to only require "insert" access to a user's Google calendar?

There's a scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events" that gives my app complete read/write access to all calendar events for a user, but that seems over-reaching, and likely to make my user's distrust the actions of my app.

Comment: Currently there is no such scope.

Answer (score 3):

The min permissions to insert events into a user calendar is read/write access.

There are 4 permissions level:
See events (no events details) 
Read (can see event details) 
Write (can see, create, edit and delete events) 
Owner (can manage the properties over the calendar)

Owner permission is much intrusive, I recommend you use writer permission level as a min permission to create events.

**Edited**

Since there is no current "write only" scope in google calendar api when we require manage events for our application one strategy could be the next:

You create a Google account "foo.calendar@gmail.com".

You grant access from this "foo.calendar" account to your application with "write" scope permission.

Now, each user of your application must create a new "Calendar" and share it with "foo.calendar@gmail.com" and the min permission "writer" as soon as we want create events for our application.

This is the "less intrusive" way for your application over the user data. Now you can create all events in this shared calendar that must be exclusive for your application events. **Important**: The user should not mix his private events with the application events in this shared calendar.

If your application will work with a lot of users and each user will have their own event over his own calendar, then your application must store somehow the calendar of each user.

Table user_calendar:

- id_user: user id
- id_calendar: google calendar shared with you
- foo: some of foo
- bar: a lot of bar

Comment: Is "write" permission only for events that I create, or does it allow me to see all events? That would seem intrusive as well.

Comment: Write permission allow you to see all events over the calendars that you grant access.

Comment: @daleyjem I've updated the answer with a possible solution for you to manage events without being intrusive.